# UserDefine Runtime Attributes doesn't work in Xcode8.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

It seems like xcode8.0 does not set the value of user runtime attributes when set from storyboard.What am trying to do is simple,set the label inside a cell as corneRadius of 10 which has width/height of 20. When i try to debug the views i got the following output which has weird width height(1000/1000..?)

> _UILabelLayer:0x600000283750; position = CGPoint (500 500); bounds = **CGRect (0 0; 1000 1000)**; delegate = >; opaque = YES; allowsGroupOpacity = YES; **cornerRadius = 10**; contentsMultiplyColor = (null); rasterizationScale = 2; contentsScale = 2>

[image]

[image]

Comment: The larger issue is the resizing bug. I suggest you file a bug report on this...

Comment: Okay i will do so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's helpful for you.

[image]

and also check the `clipToBounds`

[image]

Checking "Clip Subviews" is equal to the code `addMessageLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this code and method on your controller**

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            yourLabel.clipsToBounds = true
            yourLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
            print("Frame ------> ",yourLabel.frame)
     }
```